# Add and remove rows for bar chart created by VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need to create Bar chart in Excel VBA. I used the code below, but when I am ADDING or DELETING A ROW it is not working.

I need that chart on fixed range (`K1`). Because when I am calculating for the second time it creates another chart.

How can I change the code to prevent a new chart being added when I adjust the data source?

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Sheets("Sheet7").Range("F2:H12").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet7!$F$2:$H$12")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet7!$G$1"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=Sheet7!$H$1"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample code below it checks to see if a chart called `TheChart` already exists, and if not, creates a new one. You can now add and remove rows and the chart should will update. Additionally, if you add a new row at the bottom and click the button it will redraw `TheChart` without creating a new one.

The chart is always located at the top-left of `K1` per the `rngChartTopLeft` variable - which you can adjust if required.

The code assumes that it is running in a Sheet module (hence `Set ws = Me`) and if you were running it in a standard module you can set the sheet with `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("your_sheet")`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chto As ChartObject
    Dim rngChartTopLeft As Range
    Dim rngData As Range

    ' assumes the code is in a sheet object
    Set ws = Me

    ' top left of chart
    Set rngChartTopLeft = ws.Range("K1")

    ' create chart or get existing chart
    If ws.ChartObjects.Count = 0 Then
        Set chto = ws.ChartObjects.Add( _
            Left:=rngChartTopLeft.Left, _
            Width:=500, _
            Top:=rngChartTopLeft.Top, _
            Height:=500)
        chto.Name = "TheChart"
    Else
        Set chto = ws.ChartObjects("TheChart")
    End If

    ' set chart type
    chto.Chart.ChartType = xlBarClustered

    ' get data range per last row of data
    Set rngData = ws.Range("F2:G" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)

    ' set new chart range
    chto.Chart.SetSourceData rngData

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks man. Works perfectly. How to add series name from Cell G1 and H1 automatically. Here i add code like below. But i manually entered my sheet name. Is that okay or any other method you have. chto.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet7!$G$1"

Comment: You can try `chto.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ws.Range("G1").Value` ?

Comment: Thanks. You can change ChartType = xlColumnStacked to ChartType = xlBarClustered. It can match with this question.

Answer (score 0):

please check the below code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim mychart As Shape
Dim lastrow As Long


lastrow = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

For Each mychart In ActiveSheet.Shapes

If mychart.Name = "CommandButton1" Then GoTo exit_

mychart.Delete

exit_:

Next

Sheets("Sheet7").Range("F2:H" & lastrow).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet7!$F$2:$H$" & lastrow)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet7!$G$1"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=Sheet7!$H$1"

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code. But after clicking Commandbutton1 it suddenly disappeared.

Comment: You have right, now it works fine,i have changed the Code.